# c# Display selected rows in DataGridview

Tags: c#, winforms

My datagridview is populated with multiple rows of data, I am able to select multiple rows in my datagridview and then want to update the datagridview to display the selected rows.

In this case i am able to display selected rows if it already on screen (in short : need to scroll datagridview up to selected row if it selected or to end row)

```
do
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= stringToHighlight.Length; j++)
    {
        if (ColID > 15)
        {
            rowID++;
            ColID = 0;
        }
        if (stringToHighlight[j].ToString().ToLower() == dataGridView1.Rows[rowID].Cells[ColID].Value.ToString().ToLower())
        {
            GridView_Binary.Rows[rowID].Cells[ColID].Selected = true;
            dataGridView1.Rows[rowID].Cells[ColID].Selected = true;
            ColID++;
        }
        else
        {
            GridView_Binary.ClearSelection();
            dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
            break;
        }

        if (j == stringToHighlight.Length - 1)
        {
            ISNext = false;

            return true;
        }
    }
    ColID++;
}
while (ISNext);
```

Comment: Some code, perhaps?

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: need to scroll depends upon next selection @AleksaRistic

Comment: Which part isn't working, or are you expecting someone to write the functionality for you?

Answer (score 0):

To scroll to selected row use this:

```
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
```

if you want with all checks code would look like this:

```
//Checking if data grid view have rows
if(dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    //Checking if anything is selected
    if(dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
    {
        //Selecting first of all selected rows in datagridview
        dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
    }
    else
    {
        //Selecting last row in data grid view
        dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = (dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1);
    }
}
```